# Using count() for finding multiple characters in a string

Tags: python, count

I am using Python count() function to find the number of times a character has been repeated in a string. e.g.,
"parya".count("a")
--> 2
how can I use count for more that one character? i.e., "parya".count("a","y") --> 2,1
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count()` can only count one thing at a time. If you want the counts of two strings, call it twice.

```
("parya".count("a"), "parya".count("y"))
```

If you want the counts of everything, use `collections.Counter()`.

```
from collections import Counter

counts = collections.counter("parya")
```

This will return the dictionary

```
{"p": 1, "a": 2, "r": 1, "y": 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as a list comprehension

```
my_string = 'parya'
print([f'{character}: {my_string.count(character)}' for character in {*my_string}])
```

Output:

['p: 1', 'y: 1', 'a: 2', 'r: 1']